# API Driven Approach Vs Non-API approach

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, architecture

I am to start designing & architecting a fairly big database business application (data entry, notifications, reporting, data export and usual security restrictions for data). Multiple clients - mobile apps & multiple websites will be there. Plan to use Asp.net MVC5 & Sql server for the development. Phonegap will be used to create mobile apps.

I plan to create an API. All interactions to the Database will be through the API (a REST API). This REST API will be created using Asp.Net MVC5. The front end will be developed as an HTML5 App which calls this API using AJAX. All interactions with the API will be through AJAX calls. Need to expose some of these services (5%) to third parties also.

For e.g. for a supplier management feature, there will be services like SupplierAdd, SupplierEdit, SupplierDelete, SupplierList etc. in the API. HTML5 App will call them through AJAX and do required. Necessary security will be imposed for these services using a login and token based security system.

Plan to use some Javascript frameworks like Angular JS for front end.

The entire application is one with around 200 DB tables and lot of relationships between DB tables. Business logic is only moderately complex. This is mainly a data storage & reporting application.

Is there any problem with this full API based approach ?

Another approach suggested is to avoid AJAX and Javascript and use ASP.Net MVC itself. No separate API will be there for each operation. .cshtml will submit to the controller method and this method will call the Business Layer and do operation. Services which are needed for mobile apps and third parties alone are exposed as API. Is this a better solution ?

The issue which I see for the second approach is that when more and more mobile applications or websites come in future, it does not offer needed flexibility. Also, exposure of some of the services to third parties will be difficult.

I request experienced architects to comment.